# Invoke Class Method using Reflection with different params in constructor?

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

Hello i am very new to c# reflection and i have the following problem.

I have a CommandDispatcher class that invokes a certain Command class that does something.

For now i use a switch to determinate what command to invoke.

i wanted to simplify the code by using reflection to invoke the right command and get rid of the switch for good.

But each command takes a certain service or more in its constructor. I don't want to change that part . I understand that if i had no services passed in the constructor the code would work fine.

So how can i invoke my commands with reflection when each command takes one or many services.

Here is an image for better understanding: [The code with color indicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LyxG.png)

I left the switch not commented out for easier reading.

Here is the code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/AMQeh1zw

My search did not result in finding anything to solve my problem.

Comment: So you want to determine type of the constructor parameters and create those parameters first and then use them to create Command object via reflection ?

Comment: I think so i want for example to invoke the RegisterUserCommand.cs that takes new UserService() as a param in the constructor. 
Basicly i want to do the same thing that i do with the switch but using reflection.

Comment: I understand that.. You can do that using reflection but that won't be an easy path for sure. How do you handle if there are constructor parameters with their own constructors with parameters? You would have to go one level further for that which might end up another level going down.

Comment: Use a Dependency Injection Container

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know how to do that but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle your use case is to use IoC and DI.

For the case of reflection as of now you can determine the constructor parameters and their types for a given type by using following code.

Let say there is a class `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass
{
     int age;
     double salary;
     public MyClass(int x, double y)
     {
         age = x;
         salary = y;
     }
}
```

You can get information about all the constructors of `MyClass` using following logic

```
var ctors = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructors();
// assuming class MyClass has only one constructor
var ctor = ctors[0];
foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "Param {0} is named {1} and is of type {2}",
        param.Position, param.Name, param.ParameterType));
}
```

Now once you know the type of the constructor parameters you can create objects of those types with values assigned to them and use them to create object of `MyClass` as following.

```
var parameters = new List<object>();
foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(param.ParameterType);
    parameters.Add(obj);
}

var myClassObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), parameters.ToArray());
```

The limitation here, you would notice, is you can not set properties or values of `obj` as it is of tyoe `object`. If you convert it to specific type then you will end up having `switch case` or `if-else` ladder. So as long as the constructor of your class expects parameters of reference type (class type) this code would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Dependency Injection library for example [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) and 
[nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/).
For your purporse  you can use next construction:

This code init your Dependency Injection core

```
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

And your switch:

```
switch (commandName)
        {
            case "RegisterUser":
                RegisterUserCommand registerUser = kernel.Get<RegisterUserCommand>();
                result = registerUser.Execute(commandParameters);
                break;
            case "Login":
                LoginCommand loginCommand = kernel.Get<LoginCommand>();
                result = loginCommand.Execute(commandParameters);
                break;
    }
```